# Generate POST request for storing images in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, image-upload

I am working with WordPress to save images to its media library. Images are sent in base64 form so I want to know how we can make POST data requests for that base64 image after decoding it, as WordPress's `wp_handle_upload` function does not accept image via url.

Here is my code

```
$image = $_REQUEST['image'];  // requested image
include('../wp-load.php');  // Load wordpress engine
include_once('config.php');
$data = base64_decode($image);   // decode image
$filename = "IMG_".time().".png";  // filename 
//$fileurl = "../wp-content/uploads".$directory.$filename;
//file_put_contents($fileurl, $data);
// wordpress wp_handle_upload not accept image via url 
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
$uploadedfile = $data;
$upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
$movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );
if ( $movefile ) {
    // echo "file loaded";
}
if ( $movefile ) {
    $wp_filetype = $movefile['type'];
    $filename = $movefile['file'];
    $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $attachment = array(
        'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $filename ),
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype,
        'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($filename)),
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i did with another way , i write that decoded base64 image to uploads folder and then insert it as attachement

```
$postId = $_REQUEST['postId'];
$image = $_REQUEST['image'];
$directory = "/".date(Y)."/".date(m)."/";
$wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$data = base64_decode($image);
$filename = "IMG_".time().".png";
//$fileurl = $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $filename );
$fileurl = "../wp-content/uploads".$directory.$filename;

$filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $fileurl), null );

file_put_contents($fileurl, $data);

    $attachment = array(
        'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $fileurl ),
        'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
        'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($fileurl)),
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );
//  print_r($attachment);
//echo "<br>file name :  $fileurl";
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $fileurl ,$postId);
require_once('../wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

// Generate the metadata for the attachment, and update the database record.
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $fileurl );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
```

hope it will help someone :)

Comment: did you try removing an image when added using your approach? wp_delete_attachment does not work for me in this case.. (probably because the image is not inserted via wp_handle_upload?)

Comment: I had a problem with some server restrictins. I was not able to acces root folder via relative path. I had to use ABSPATH instead. So I edited a few lines of your code like this
`
$filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $fileurl), null );
require_once(ABSPATH.'/wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
`